# Defining a range with two variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a variable to a range that is defined using two other variables.

SchRow and SchCol vary depending on the date, Mnum and Shift entered into the user form.  I keep getting the Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error and I cannot figure out why as all of the variables are defined.  I even tried to convert the column number result from SchCol into a letter and that did not work either.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
    'Define variables to search for scheduled up time
    Dim SchDate As Range
    Dim FDate As String
    Dim SchTime As String
    Dim SchRow As String
    Dim SchCol As String

    FDate = .Range("A" & FirstEmptyRow).Value

    'Search the schedule tab to find the scheduled up time
    With Sheets("Schedule")

        Set SchDate = Sheets("Schedule").Range("C3:W57").Find(FDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
        'MsgBox (SchDate.Address)
        If SchDate Is Nothing Then

            MsgBox ("Date Not Found, re-enter data with correct date")
            GoTo Terminate

            Else

            SchRow = SchDate.Row + MNum
            'MsgBox (SchRow)
            SchCol = SchDate.Column + Shift - 1
            'MsgBox (SchCol)
            SchTime = .Range(SchCol & SchRow).Value * 60
            'This is where I get the Run time error '1004':
                MsgBox (SchTime)

        End If

    End With
```

The SchRow and SchCol return the correct numbers as expected, but the SchTime errors out.  I want to get the value from the cell in the location defined using SchRow and SchCol.

Comment: Those values changes based on the date the user enters.  The SchDate finds the date on the Schedule tab and the I move depending on the Mnum or machine number and the Shift that is input to get the schedules up time for that machine on that day for that shift.  I have been testing with the date 8/26/2019, hat value is located in cellF40 on my spreadsheet.  So for machine #1, Shift #2 on 8/26/2019, the values are SchRow = 41, SchCol = 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SchCol` is a number not a letter and `Range()` expects a letter.  Change the variables to `Long` and use `Cells()`

```
'Define variables to search for scheduled up time
Dim SchDate As Range
Dim FDate As String
Dim SchTime As String
Dim SchRow As Long
Dim SchCol As Long

FDate = .Range("A" & FirstEmptyRow).Value

'Search the schedule tab to find the scheduled up time
With Sheets("Schedule")

    Set SchDate = Sheets("Schedule").Range("C3:W57").Find(FDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
    'MsgBox (SchDate.Address)
    If SchDate Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox ("Date Not Found, re-enter data with correct date")
        GoTo Terminate

        Else

        SchRow = SchDate.Row + MNum
        'MsgBox (SchRow)
        SchCol = SchDate.Column + Shift - 1
        'MsgBox (SchCol)
        SchTime = .Cells(SchRow, SchCol).Value * 60
        'This is where I get the Run time error '1004':
            MsgBox (SchTime)

    End If

End With
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you so much, life saver!